# What is Annotation counterpart for Spring <context:property-override>?

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

We can externalize properties using `<context:property-placeholder>` and we can override the Spring bean properties by configuring `<context:property-override>` as follows:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>
<context:property-override location="classpath:override.properties"/>
```

I want to move my XML config to JavaConfig.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean  
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {  
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();  
    }

}
```

But how to configure my override properties using Annotation?

PS:
I have a bean say MyBean as follows:

```
@Component
public class MyBean {

    @Value("${someProp}")
    private String someProp;
}
```

In my `application.properties` I have

```
someProp=TestValue
```

and in my `override.properties` i am overriding someProp value as

```
myBean.someProp=RealValue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, It isn't.

But you could create a bean of type `PropertyOverrideConfigurer` in the configuration class whit the same result.

**Update**

For example:

```
@Bean public static PropertyOverrideConfigurer  propertyOverrideConfigurer() { 
    PropertyOverrideConfigurer overrideConfigurer = new PropertyOverrideConfigurer(); 
    overrideConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("override.properties"));
    return overrideConfigurer; 
}
```

Note the **static** modifier, this is because BFPP should be instantiated early in the container lifecycle.

see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html for more info.

Comment: Created a Bean definition as follows and worked fine:

@Bean  
    public PropertyOverrideConfigurer propertyOverrideConfigurer() {  

  PropertyOverrideConfigurer overrideConfigurer = new PropertyOverrideConfigurer();

  overrideConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("override.properties"));

        return overrideConfigurer;  

    }

Comment: Although your answer is correct you might want to elaborate it a bit more (and maybe put in some links to javadoc). Also when adding a `PropertyOverrideConfigurer` as a bean in javaconfig it should be a `public static` method instead of a `public` method.